# docusign REST API How to return signer to a url after signing PHP

Tags: docusignapi

I am building some functions to create my JSON using the sign-client PHP API and Models. I am create an envelope on docusign using the API and sending signers emails where they go to docusign to sign. I am not using embedded signing. I am doing this all though the API and plan to get and API plan so will not have all the web-based access.

I have one or more signers and after they sign I need to direct them to a URL on my site where they can make a payment. This URL us specific to each envelope, not the same for all signers.

I believe what I need to add is a 'returnUrl' to the createEnvelope so after the users sign, they are redirected back to my site. Here is what I have, but it is not working.

```
$signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer->setName($signer_details['name']);
$signer->setEmail($signer_details['email']);
$signer->setRoleName($signer_details['role']);
$signer->setRecipientId(1);
$signer->setRoutingOrder(1);
$signer->setEmailRecipientPostSigningUrl('https://www.example.com');
```

By default, after signing the signer is given a docusign page. I am pretty sure there is a variable I can use to redirect them to my site. Anyone know how to do this?

Thom

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `emailRecipientPostSigningUrl` parameter is currently undocumented. I've asked the DocuSign engineering group for more information on it.

**Meanwhile,** please provide more information on what you want to do. Are you using embedded signing or signing via email notification from DocuSign?

Please **edit** your question to provide the additional information.

**Added**

As indicated in other answers, if you want to have a per-envelope URL then you either:

1. Use embedded signing. This is probably your best bet.
2. Or use the one url for all envelopes  (via branding), then *that* url determines the real url for the envelope and further redirects the signer. I don't know if your first url receives the envelope_id or other information about what the signer did.

Comment: Edited question with more info.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think I will use webhooks to send payment emails with the URL once all signers have signed.

Comment: @thorn -- That sounds like a good solution. Loosely coupled apps are often best.

Comment: Did you ever hear from DocuSign regarding `emailRecipientPostSigningURL`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect signer back to your App after signing is completed then you can configure Destination URL in your Branding. You can find details [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding), check `Destination URLs for post-signing navigation` section. Destination URL in Branding will be used only for Remote Signing.

Answer (score 1):

1. The returnUrl property only applies for embedded signing.
2. Otherwise you would not be able to set it via the API - you would need to set it in the Branding options under "Go to Admin" and then "Brands" and then default brand, "Edit" and then "Destination URLs" and you can set the return URL for signing there based on the action that the signer takes.

Embedded signing allows you to set the returnUrl parameter and use a distinct URL for every session to return back to a specific place in your application instead of a generic one.

See https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html